# Ruby scan regex will not match optional

Tags: ruby, regex

Take this string.

```
a = "real-ab(+)real-bc(+)real-cd-xy"
a.scan(/[a-z_0-9]+\-[a-z_0-9]+[\-\[a-z_0-9]+\]?/)
=> ["real-ab", "real-bc", "real-cd-xy"]
```

But how come this next string gets nothing?

```
a = "real-a(+)real-b(+)real-c"
a.scan(/[a-z_0-9]+\-[a-z_0-9]+[\-\[a-z_0-9]+\]?/)
=> []
```

How can I have it so both strings output into a 3 count array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've confused parentheses (used for grouping) and square brackets (used for character classes). You want

```
a.scan(/[a-z_0-9]+-[a-z_0-9]+(?:-[a-z_0-9]+)?/)
```

`(?:...)` creates a non-capturing group which is what you need here.

Furthermore, unless you want to disallow uppercase letters explicitly, you can write `\w` as a shorthand for "a letter, digit or underscore":

```
a.scan(/\w+-\w+(?:-\w+)?/)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.scan(/[a-z_0-9]+\-[a-z_0-9]+/)
```

Comment: Won't match `real-cd-xy` completely.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply?

```
a.scan(/[a-z_0-9\-]+/)
```

Comment: Maybe. But it would also match a string that doesn't contain any dashes, and they were not optional in his regex. Or strings like `---` or `real-` or `-real`, all of which are not legal by his first regex.